# Mostrar mensaje de error en un span de un formulario en javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hice una validacion pero quiero que el mensaje de **debe llenar todos los campos** se muestre en un span con javascript:

```
function validarformulario(){

var nombre,correo,compañia,expresion;
nombre =document.getElementById('nombre').value;
correo=document.getElementById('email').value;
compañia=document.getElementById('compañia').value;

expresion= /^[-\w.%+]{1,64}@(?:[A-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.){1,125}[A-Z]{2,63}$/i;

if ( nombre ==="" || compañia==="" || correo==="" ) { 
   error.html(<'span>Todos los campos son obligatorios</span>');
          return false
}
else if (!expresion.test(email.value)){ 
      error.html('<span>Please enter a valid email address</span>');
       return false
     }
}
```

Comment: Hola, puedes colocar tu código que sea ejecutable y muestre el error y lo que deseas por favor.

Comment: Te lanza algun error?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var errorSpan = document.getElementById("formError");

errorSpan.innerHTML = "Rellena todos los campos" // plain javascript

// $("#errorSpan").html("Rellena todos los campos");  Jquery
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <span id="formError"></span>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que algo asi es lo que quieres, pero aclarando un poco las dudas sobre tu codigo, quiza no te funcione por la forma que tienes declaras las variables, 
con eso me refiero a esto, **var nombre, compañia, email;**
Tienes que declararlas individualmente, **var nombre; var compañia; etc.**
Ademas te recomiendo que no uses la **Ñ** en nombres de variables.
Ademas para ver este tipo de errores puedes usar la consola del navegador, presionado F12 en la mayoria de navegadores, y busca la pestaña Consola(Console) y alli aparecen los errores, si es que los hay.

Espero te sirva, saludos.

```js
function validarformulario(){

        var nombre;
        var correo; 
        var company;
        var expresion;
        nombre =document.getElementById('nombre').value;
        correo=document.getElementById('email').value;
        company=document.getElementById('compañia').value;

        expresion= /^[-\w.%+]{1,64}@(?:[A-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.){1,125}[A-Z]{2,63}$/i;

        if ( nombre ==="" || company==="" || correo ==="" ) { 
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Todos los campos son obligatorios";
            return false
        }
        else if (!expresion.test(email.value)){ 
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email address";
            return false
        }
    }
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="nombre">
    <input type="text" id="email">
    <input type="text" id="compañia">
    <button  onclick="validarformulario()">Validar</button><br>
    <span id="demo"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <meta charsef="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="" id="nombre" placeholder="nombre">        
        <input type="text" name="" id="email" placeholder="email">
        <input type="text" name="" id="compania" placeholder="compañia">
        <button type="button" onclick="validarformulario()"> Enviar</button>
        <span></span>        
      </div>
      
      <script>
        function validarformulario(){

          var nombre,correo,compania,expresion;
          nombre =document.getElementById('nombre').value;
          correo=document.getElementById('email').value;
          compania=document.getElementById('compania').value;

          expresion= /^[-\w.%+]{1,64}@(?:[A-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.){1,125}[A-Z]{2,63}$/i;

            if ( nombre ==="" || compania==="" || correo==="" ) { 
               
               $("span").html("<span>Todos los campos son obligatorios</span>");
                  return false
            }
            else if (!expresion.test(email.value)){ 
                $("span").html('<span>Please enter a valid email address</span>');
                 return false
               }
        }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Quizas esto te puede servir Saludos !!!!

Comment: Se debe comentar que realiza y que puede ayudar a solucionar, Revisar [answer].